# How do server-sent events work with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I have an ASP.NET MVC application and I am using server-sent events. The application works fine but I am having some questions on how it works.
Below is the controller code.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "SSE WITH ASP.NET MVC";
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Message() 
        {
          var result = string.Empty;
          var sb = new StringBuilder();
          sb.AppendFormat("data: {0}\n\n", DateTime.Now.ToString());
          return Content(sb.ToString(), "text/event-stream");

      }
    }
```

And below is the view code.

```
<script>

    function contentLoaded() {
        var source = new EventSource('home/message');
        //var ul = $("#messages");
        source.onmessage = function (e) {

            var li = document.createElement("li");
            var returnedItem = e.data;
            li.textContent = returnedItem;
            $("#messages").append(li);
        }
    };

    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", contentLoaded, false);
</script>
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<p>
    SSE WITH ASP.NET MVC
</p>
<ul id="messages">
</ul>
```

My questions are:
1. The time gets updated only every 3 seconds. Why is it so?
2. How to determine how often the controller action will be called?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The time gets updated only every 3 seconds. Why is it so?

Because your `Controller` is returning the `ActionResult` containing a single data and then closing the connection, so the browser [waits 3 seconds](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/comms.html#concept-event-stream-reconnection-time) and then re-opens it.

> How to determine how often the controller action will be called?

The same way you would determine how often any other method will be called, with loops and [delays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep.aspx).

SSE is *Server* Sent Events, you manage all this stuff from the server side, it'll only work properly if you explicitly hold the connection open, otherwise you may as well do AJAX polling from the client instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I have a better picture of the connection. In that case how would a typical Controller action look like when SSE is being used? Do you have any example or can you provide me with a link where it is explained.

Comment: The OP's code seems to be based on this blog post http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2012/04/10/using-html5-server-sent-events-with-json-and-aspnet-mvc/ which completely misses the points of server-sent events.