# ASP.NET MVC 5 AJAX - Update chat room when local & remote users post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to create a simple chat room in ASP.NET MVC 5.

Creating models, view models & using an AJAX ActionLink I can let one user post new data to a partially updated area of the page easily. I have found plenty of examples of this online.

However, I also need to update the 'chat / message window' when the external user sends a message too. How can I send these events to the client - and how can I update the chat by only adding what the external user said (not refreshing all the text of the chat)?

thx.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr)

Comment: thanks - are you saying there's no good way to do it in AJAX? Any pointers?

Comment: SignalR handles this easily for sure. I have implemented something like this before by creating a timer in JavaScript that pulls every 5 seconds or so asking the endpoint/controller if there are new messages. If so, I get the message in Json and I update the partial accordingly -- I was saving the messages to a database, so I can pull.

Comment: You can do it in pure ajax as @EddiePaz mentioned, but I think it would be better to use already established frameworks rather than reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for new messages every few seconds but this is not a best approach as it includes unnecessary server hits.

The best approach is to use SignalR which abstracts the way your web server can notify the connected clients, these clients can be a browser, desktop or mobile and this is where SignalR really excels.

This tutorial explains exactly what you need step by step

https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Answer (score 0):

If this is a simple chat room, without any "advanced" features, like private messages etc. then the most light-weight solution would be to use server-side events (SSE).

You can take a look at a stackoverflow article here: ["How do server-sent events work with ASP.NET MVC?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940509/how-do-server-sent-events-work-with-asp-net-mvc)

SignalR is a great solution, but to work best, it requires web-sockets, something not all hosting options include. SSE does not require any additional features on the server.

Comment: As I understand it SignalR will gracefully degrade to a number of technologies.

Comment: It will, but it's still a lot of code to include, just to have a chat room, if there are no requirements for private messages etc. And SignalR also needs jQuery.

Comment: actually it requires virtually no code at all - have you used it? You are up and running in about 2 minutes and 5 lines of code - the whole point is is saves time & boosts abilities.

Comment: Yes I have, I've developed a game chat/lobby with it, a couple of years ago. It just makes sense to post this reply anyway, as there's another option, that works out of the box with ASP.NET MVC (and ASP.NET Core, where SignalR isn't ready yet).